# Structure of PH4Br

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-structure

What is the structure of $\ce{PH4Br}$? I would like to know which atom is bonded to which. Are all five atoms directly bonded to phosphorus?

Answer (score 5):

No, not in the solid state. The most recent crystal structure analysis suggests there are nearly ideal tetrahedra of phosphonium cations $\ce{PH4+}$ with bromine anions $\ce{Br-}$ in between bound via H-bonds [1, ICSD#23691]:

[image]

#### Reference

1. Schroeder, L. W.; Rush, J. J. The Journal of Chemical Physics 1971, 54 (5), 1968–1973. [DOI 10.1063/1.1675127](https://doi.org/10.1063%2F1.1675127).

Comment: andelisk, does PH4Br exist as a liquid or gas?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler $\ce{PH4Br}$ sublimes at approx. 30 °C.

Comment: andelisk So what should prevent me to imagine that phospine and hydrogen bromide still exist in the solide phase and they simply sorted in a crystalline order? (I’m really a newbie in chemistry, so sorry for the naive question.)

Comment: @HolgerFiedler Well, you can imagine anything you want, but neutron diffraction suggests otherwise (BTW have you checked the paper cited?).

Comment: Behind a paywall? Doesn’t the sublimation of you HBr2 point to a very week bonding. Or more to a very homogeneous mixture?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler Oh, I'm very sorry, I thought you had access to the paper. You are right, the compound is rather unstable at ambient conditions and readily recombines to $\ce{PH3}$ and $\ce{HBr}$ upon sublimation.